# group by clause in oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g and wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT presenttime,
       employeeid
  FROM mobilelocation
 WHERE presentdate = '31-10-2011'
 GROUP BY employeeid;
```

resulting an error message

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But upon removing this group clause returining the result without any errors like this,

```
PRESENTTIME EMPLOYEEID
23:25   12304
23:48   12305
```

What is the problem with my group by clause and also suggest me how to use **order by** clause also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY` implies that you want to aggregate multiple rows from the table into a single row for every `EmployeeID` value.  If that is your goal, you'd need to specify an aggregate function on the columns that you are not grouping by.  If you want the earliest `PresentTime` value for each `EmployeeID`, for example, you'd do something like

```
SELECT EmployeeID, MIN(PresentTime) earliestPresentTime
  FROM mobileLocation
 WHERE PresentDate = date '2011-10-31'
 GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by both presenttime, employeeID

As far as order by; its similar to group by.

Order by employeeID, presentTIme (desc)

any item in the select portion must be in the group by portion if an aggregrate wasn't defined (min, max, sum, count, etc.)